# CakePHP Pagination with a model which has a HABTM model

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have 3 models (artist, media item, accent)

Artist hasMany media items,
Media items hasAndBelongsToMany accents,

Now what I am having issues with is how to search with pagination, I need to get pages of 8 artists and the media_items which match the accent entered. Hopefully that makes sense.

This is what I have currently

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'limit' => 8,
    'fields' => array("Artist.first_name",
                        "Artist.last_name", "Artist.image",
                        "Artist.image", "Artist.slug"),
    'order' => "Artist.last_name",
    'url' => $this->passedArgs,
    'contain' => array(
                    'MediaItem'=> array(
                        "fields" => array("MediaItem.file",
                                            "MediaItem.title",
                                            "MediaItem.accent",)
                ),
    'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'media_items',
                        'type' => 'INNER',
                        'alias' => 'MediaItem',
                        'conditions' => array(
                                "AND" => array('Artist.id = MediaItem.artist_id')
                            )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'table' => 'media_accents_media_items',
                        'type' => 'RIGHT',
                        'alias' => 'MediaAccentsMediaItems',
                        'conditions' => array(
                                "AND" => array('MediaAccentsMediaItems.media_item_id = MediaItem.id')
                            )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'table' => 'media_accents',
                        'type' => 'RIGHT',
                        'alias' => 'MediaAccent',
                        'conditions' => array(
                                "AND" => array('MediaAccent.id = MediaAccentsMediaItems.media_accent_id'),
                                "OR" => array('MediaAccent.name LIKE' => "%".$searchFor ."%")
                            )
                    )
                ),
    'group' => 'Artist.id',
    'update' => '.results-container',
    'evalScripts' => true
);
```

it gets the right artists but returns all their tracks rather than the ones I need. Is there a better way rather than looping through the results pruning them? Which is my current backup plan.

Answer (score 1):

Remove joins and just use Containable Behavior, here is [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations) for deeper associations.

Comment: Have got that kinda working though not with how the paginator needs to work. Essentially Media accent -> media item -> artists if I read the doc you linked to right. Just need to get it to paginate by the artists now.

Comment: As it stands I'm getting 1 media accent result with n media items with their associated aritst which is kinda the reverse of what i'm after but thank you anyway :)